# Problem building in groovy with catkin and boost

Tags: ros, catkin, boost, buiding-errors, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Not sure what I've missed here - Just changed over from furte to groovy following http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild. Everything was fine before. I've created a new catkin project area and just copied my code over. But for everything that uses ros i.e. #include "ros/ros.h" etc

```
[ 33%] Built target NetworkInterface
[ 66%] Built target RobotInterface
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ToeminatorROSBridge.dir/src/ToeminatorROSBridge.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/boost/math/tools/config.hpp:13:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:13,
             from /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/time.h:58,
             from /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/ros.h:38,
             from /home/pi/ros-apps/toeminator_ros_bridge2/src/ToeminatorROSBridge.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/config.hpp:35:33: fatal error: boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ToeminatorROSBridge.dir/src/ToeminatorROSBridge.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ToeminatorROSBridge.dir/all] Error 2
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**
Adding `CmakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(toeminator_ros_bridge2)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs tf)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)

catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES toeminator_ros_bridge2
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs tf
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
) 

include_directories(... ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(RobotInterface src/RobotInterface.cpp)
add_library(NetworkInterface src/NetworkInterface.cpp)


add_executable(ToeminatorROSBridge src/ToeminatorROSBridge.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ToeminatorROSBridge RobotInterface)
target_link_libraries(ToeminatorROSBridge NetworkInterface)
```

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60489/problem-building-in-groovy-with-catkin-and-boost/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-11**:
Please update your question to add the relevant parts of your CMakeLists.txt, especially where you use the target_link_libraries() macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure that you are including the boost header path in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread ...)
...
include_directories(... ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
```

---

**EDIT:**

The ellipsis `...` are not meant to be used literally, I would modify your `CMakeLists.txt` to look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(toeminator_ros_bridge2)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs tf)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES RobotInterface NetworkInterface
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs tf
  DEPENDS Boost
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(RobotInterface src/RobotInterface.cpp)
target_link_libraries(RobotInterface ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
add_library(NetworkInterface src/NetworkInterface.cpp)
target_link_libraries(NetworkInterface ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(ToeminatorROSBridge src/ToeminatorROSBridge.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ToeminatorROSBridge
  RobotInterface
  NetworkInterface
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

This might be linking somethings unnecessarily, but it should work.  Without looking at how each of your libraries and executables are using ROS stuff and Boost I cannot know how to write your build file exactly right.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2013-04-12**:
Thanks for the info - Added those to the makefile - still no change :(

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-04-13**:
You added them to the `CMakeLists.txt` or the `Makefile`? They should go in the `CMakeLists.txt`